# What are the steps should we take to analyze a dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science

I am new in the field of data science, and I want to know about the key steps to get the properties of any dataset used for machine learning tasks.

Comment: This is covered in heavy detail in many introductory ML books, articles, and courses

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  You've asked for a broad-based primer on an entire field of study; this is out of Scope for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is too general you need to specify more. What do you mean by the properties of the dataset?
Nevertheless I'll try to answer what I understood from your question.

After choosing what kind of problem you have (classification or regression) you'll want to try and visualize your data to get a better sense of what you are doing.

Facets is an excellent tool to do this https://pair-code.github.io/facets/ . It will help you better comprehend how your data is distributed and maybe give you some extra insight on how to tackle your problem but how you use it depends on the problem you have.

You should also visualize your correlation matrix to see whether you have features that are heavily correlated and thus you can remove unnecessary features.

I remember when I started working on my first machine learning project things were overwhelming but the best tip I can give you is try to find a step by step guide that deals with a similar problem you are facing I'm sure you'll find plenty and try to clarify more your question we could give you more insight

Answer (score 2):

What you ask is very general and your request is not well defined, but, I'll try to give you a short introduction to get you started.
knowledge required (as I see it):

- Statistics and probability
- Basic knowledge in mathematics
- Basic knowledge of AI techniques and algorithms

The first step is every research is to define the problem, what are you trying to do?

for instance:

> "I would like to predict if the next person who buys this car is a male or a female"

This kind of problem is a **Classification** problem, which means, the solution will label the "input" person as a male or a female correctly.
This is called a model, a model is a representation of the real world and its properties and using ML tools we wish to create it.

We do that by looking into history data, for example, lets say that out of 1000 male costumers and 1000 females, 850 males bought car X, while the rest bought car Y and 760 females bought car Y and the rest bought X.

now, if I tell you the next costumer bought car X, can you tell me its gender?

you are probably thinking its a male, but theres still a chance for it to be a female, yet, theres a higher probability it is in fact a male since we already know the pattern of male's and female's choices.
that's basically how it works, given a dataset, such as yours, you need to use it in order to predict something out of it.

> Note: rather if your dataset is fit for this or not, or how much of an information gain you'll get from it is another story.

Now, each piece of data you can learn from is called a record:

> first_name: 'LEROY', last_name: 'JENKINS', age: '25', gender: 'male' car_bought: 'x'

and each property is called a feature.
some features can be useless to you, in our example, only the gender is important, and the rest are useless, learning according to the useless feature may cause your model to learn invalid data.
also, some records may contain invalid data such is NULLs and missing data, first thing needed to do is to **pre-process** your data and get it ready for the learning.

once your data is ready, you can start the training, for that, you'll have to choose the most suitable algorithm for you, I wont go over the algorithms because there are a lot and you'll have to gain more knowledge about those, but there are many libraries for those and you should just google it.

I'll give you a short code example for a simple neural network usage to get you started to predict the outcome of a simple mathematical function: **F(x) = 2*x**

```
# prepare the dataset
X = np.arange(0.0, 1000.0, 1.0)
Y = np.empty(shape=0, dtype=float)
for x in X:
    Y = np.append(Y, float(2*x)))
return X, Y
```

and a simple neural network using keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

# compile model
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# train model
m = model.fit(self.x_train, self.y_train, epochs=500, batch_size=1)
```

predicting using the output model:

```
for i in np.arange(2000.0, 2010.0, 1.0):
    df = pandas.DataFrame()
    df['X'] = [i]
    print('f(',i,') = ',model.predict(df)[0][0])
```

will output:

```
f(2000.0) = 4000.0
f(2001.0) = 4002.0
f(2002.0) = 4004.0
.
.
```

even if the model never saw these numbers before it can now predict the output from learning the pattern from the dataset.
I dont expect you to understand how **keras** works or what it does, only to give you the feel of what is it like to use a ML algorithm.

I hope that answered your question and it can help you get started yourself.